# Google Maps API geocoder (V3), how to set language on google.maps.GeocoderResult

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any property that I can use in Google Maps geocoder (V3) to dynamically set  language in result (`google.maps.GeocoderResult`)?. Not using html header scrip tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=vi-VN"></script>`

for example

```
var G = new google.maps.Geocoder(); // google geocoder
G.geocode({'location': ll/*, 'language':'vi-VN'*/}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0]) {                   
        me.set({'locate':results[0].address_components});
        me.set({'address':results[0].formatted_address});
    } else {
        alert("No results found");
    }
} else {
    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
}
```

Reason I want to build a region tree to connect point  have same region

```
        us
      /     \ 
   new york  ...
    /  \
   p1   p2
```

as shown, p1 and p2 are in the same region 'new-york'

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe it used to be possible to do this in v2, but in v3, the choices are browser prefs, language localization via paramater in the API script URL, and region localization which is also via parameter in the API script URL.

If you want to share more information about your use case, it may be possible to come up with a solution/workaround.

Comment: @Tritt :Thanks for your suggestion, I have update some information

Comment: Why do you want to set the language dynamically?  p1 and p2 are in the same region.  Ok.  So what?  Why do you want to show results in a language other than the language chosen by the user via their browser preferences?